# ;++ operator in ;++this.length statement

Tags: javascript

I came across a round robin implementation in javascript that I would like some clarity on.

```js
module.exports = RoundRobin

function RoundRobin(values) {
  this.values = values ? values.slice() : []
  this.length = this.values.length
  this.position = 0
}

RoundRobin.prototype.next = function() {
  if (this.position >= this.length) this.position = 0
  return this.values[this.position++]
}

RoundRobin.prototype.add = function(value) {
  if (!~this.values.indexOf(value)) {
    this.values.push(value)
    ;++this.length
  }

  return this
}

RoundRobin.prototype.has = function(value) {
  return !!~this.values.indexOf(value)
}

RoundRobin.prototype.remove = function(value) {
  var index = this.values.indexOf(value)
  if (index == -1) return false

  this.values.splice(index, 1)
  ;--this.length
  if (index < this.position) --this.position
  return true
}

RoundRobin.prototype.clear = function() {
  this.values = []
  this.length = 0
  this.position = 0
}
```

If you notice, there are some statements where they do
";++this.length", or something of similar flavor.

I understand what ++ does when placed before or after a property.

But what is that semicolon doing before the ++? Should that not come after the statement?

Credits to js-square-batman for this implementation.

Comment: There is no ;++ operator, it doesn’t matter where the ; is entered.

Comment: Where did you find this piece of code? This is a particularly bad coding convention. There is no `;++` operator just a semicolon followed by increment. They use it because they rely on ASI, which does not work like expected in this case, so they put semicolons manually. The result looks arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

The semicolon is used because the author of the code doesn't put terminators on the lines' end and `++` / `--` (as he thought) could be considered as a part of the expression on the previous line.

So, to avoid the possible error the author put the terminator on the line where it happens.

This is how it usually is

```
let a;

a = 1;

++a;
```

and this is how the author does the same:

```
let a

a = 1

;++a // and here it is not necessary...
```

As it properly pointed by @dfsq the semicolon can be safely removed. It does not make sense here.

You can call this approach something similar to semicolon-greedy :D

This is just a guess anyway. The root of the guess is here:

```
let b = 123
(function() {})()
```

This is invalid code because the `()` operator has a higher priority than the newline. And this is a normal problem which you would face if you don't put semicolons in the end of the line on a regular basis. That's why those people are used to the following:

```
let b = 123
;(function() {})()
```

This will work fine and that's how the semicolon-greedy people make it work.

Comment: This was obviously the goal of the author of the code, however in this case `;` is useless as there is no danger in having line start with `++` or `--`. `;` can be safely removed in this case.

Comment: you are absoultetly right. This just looks like some artifact from the places where it is / was really possible. The only thing I wanted is to explain why it looks like it looks. I updated the answer